# Converting CSV file to .xlsx file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert a CSV file to a .xlsx file, where the source CSV file is saved on my Desktop. I want the output file to be saved to my Desktop.

I have tried the below code. However, I am getting a 'file not found' error and 'create the parser' error. I do not know what these errors mean.

I seek:

1. Help to fix the script and
2. Help understanding the causes of the problem.

```py
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\anthonyedwards\Desktop\credit_card_input_data.csv')
read_file.to_excel(r'C:\Users\anthonyedwards\Desktop\credit_card_output_data.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: Have you checked that your Desktop is actually at `C:\Users\anthonyedwards\Desktop`? OneDrive for example relocates it. Your code is fine otherwise, so it really just is the file probably not really being there exactly.

Comment: I used the pwd command which returned '/Users/anthonyedwards' and then the file is saved on my Desktop. Is there any other way to check the file pathway?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/):

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', 'file.csv')):
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
    workbook.close()
```

FYI, there is also a package called [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/), that can read/write Excel 2007 xlsx/xlsm files.

Comment: These are alternative ways to achieve the same as OP's code, but don't address their problem (which is that the file simply isn't found)

Comment: I am very new to Python. I will do some research so I can understand the suggested script, but does anyone know the source of my specific problem / how I can find the correct file path?

Comment: Did you tried replacing the single backslash "\" with double backslashes "\\" in the file path?